# Unable to locate appropriate constructor error for nested list object in kotlin and JpaRepository

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing the following error when JPA attempts to map the result from a query to the result repository method DTO:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.example.dto.User]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.example.repository.DbRole
```

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa` plugin in my Kotlin project. I have a repository defined like this:

```
@Repository
internal interface JdbcUserRepository : UserRepository, JpaRepository<DbUser, String> {

    override fun findUserByUsername(username: String): User?
}
```

Note that type used by JpaRepository (DbUser) is different from the one retuned by the findUserByUsername method (User) and also on the error above the User class is correctly found by JPA (*...class [com.example.dto.User]...*) but Role doesn't. It's expecting a DbRole in the destination DTO, what is wrong.

DbUser is an @Entity annotated class and refers to another @Entity annotated class called DbRole. Both are defined below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
internal data class DbUser(
    @Id @Column val username: String,
    @Column val password: String,
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")]
    ) val roles: List<DbRole>
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
internal data class DbRole(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long,
    @Column val roleName: String,
    @Column val description: String
)
```

And below are the classes where JPA must map results to:

```
data class User(
    val username: String,
    val password: String,
    val roles: List<Role>
)

data class Role(val roleName: String, val description: String)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem and JPA correctly find and map the nested entity list of DbRole to the nested DTO list of Role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that database query is able to return plain result only. Persistence provider can convert it to entities with nested entities lists. As for `dto` you have to solve the problem yourself.

So you can get plain result using `User` dto with constructor as below

```
public User(String username, String password, String roleName, String roleDescription) {
     this.username = username;
     this.password = password;
     roles = new ArrayList<>();
     roles.add(new Role(roleName, roleDescription));  
}
```

Then you need repository method like this

```
@Query("select new com.example.dto.User(u.username, u.password, r.roleName, r.description) from DbUser u join u.roles r where u.username=:username")
List<User> findUserByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

Handle result in service layer

```
public Optional<User> findUserByUsername(username) {
    List<User> users = findUserByUsername(username);

    if(users.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    User user = users.get(0);
    if(users.size() > 1) {
         users.subList(1, users.size()).forEach(u -> user.getRoles().addAll(u.getRoles()));
    }

    return Optional.of(user);
}
```

You can use the same approach for `Kotlin`

Answer (score 0):

Why does your `JdbcUserRepository` returns a `User` object for `findUserByUsername` and not a `DbUser`? The solution should be obvious:

```
override fun findUserByUsername(username: String): DbUser?
```

And you do the mapping afterwards manually.

You should think that people know why they introduced multiple representations of the same object instead of using a single representation as long as possible...

Comment: "Why does your JdbcUserRepository returns a User object for findUserByUsername and not a DbUser?" For separation of concerns between usecases level and data/repository level following clean architecture principles. Usecases don't have any dependency from outermost levels otherwise it would be an inward flow violation, in this case, objects that define the DB being referenced by usecases.

Comment: What you are writing almost doesn't make any sense. Mapping between database and model is done regardless of what you may call it. But instead of having a simple 1:1 relationship between your database and your entities and mapping information between your entities and your model manually you want the mapping to be done "magically" by JPA and therefore complicating your mapping algorithm. What use is the DbUser anyway if you can "simply" use the User for all reading operations? And why does your database need to know the User and the DbUser and not only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do an adtional step of casting like so `cast(ds.demoId as java.lang.String)`
[check this out :](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

```
@Query( value = "select new com.api.models.DsResultStatus("+
            "cast(ds.demoId as java.lang.String),cast(ds.comp as java.lang.String),cast(ds.dc as java.lang.String),cast(be.buildUrl as java.lang.String)" +
            ",cast(be.username as java.lang.String),cast(tr.title as java.lang.String),cast(tr.result as java.lang.String))  \n" +
            "from DsEntity ds \n" +
            "inner join BtEntity be  ON ds.id = be.demoAssGuardingEntity\n" +
            "inner join  TrEntity tr ON be.id = tr.buildEntity\n" +
            "where ds.demoId in (?1) " +
            "and tr.title in ('\"Amazon\"','\"Google\"','\"FB\"') and tr.result = '\"failed\"'")

List<DemoAssGuardingBuildResultStatus> getAssIdsWithFaliures(@Param("demoIds") Set<String> demoIds);
```