# How to select specific fields and return the map as the result on a one to many query with spring data jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

There are two entities including Country and City whose relationship is one to many. The query result I want is a Map and child entity city as a Country field cityList should be also returned in one query, no N+1 query.

Entity code:

**City**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class City {
    private Integer cityId;
    private String cityName;
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "city_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(int cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "city_name", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_update", nullable = true)
    public Timestamp getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }


}
```

**Country**

```
@Entity
public class Country {
    private Integer countryId;
    private String countryName;
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;
    private List<City> cityList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(int countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "country_name", nullable = true, length = 255)
    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_update", nullable = true)
    public Timestamp getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    public List<City> getCityList() {
        return cityList;
    }

    public void setCityList(List<City> cityList) {
        this.cityList = cityList;
    }


}
```

**Repo**

```
public interface CountryRepo extends JpaRepository<Country, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select  new map(c.countryId as countryId , c.countryName as countryName , c.cityList as cityList)  from Country c left join fetch c.cityList")
    List findAllCountry3();

}
```

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    countryId: 1,
    countryName: "China",
    cityList: [
      {
        cityId: 1,
        cityName: "Dalian",
        lastUpdate: "2020-04-03T10:28:57.000+0000"
      },
      {
        cityId: 2,
        cityName: "Beijing",
        lastUpdate: "2020-04-03T10:29:15.000+0000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    countryId: 2,
    countryName: "US",
    cityList: [
      {
        cityId: 3,
        cityName: "New York",
        lastUpdate: "2020-04-03T10:29:47.000+0000"
      },
      {
        cityId: 4,
        cityName: "Florda",
        lastUpdate: "2020-04-03T10:30:05.000+0000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    countryId: 3,
    countryName: "Japan",
    cityList: [
      {
        cityId: 5,
        cityName: "Tokyo",
        lastUpdate: "2020-04-05T06:47:16.000+0000"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I started spring boot, I got below error.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=org.fxbird.entity.Country.cityList,tableName=city,tableAlias=citylist1_,origin=country country0_,columns={country0_.country_id ,className=org.fxbird.entity.City}}]
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: just remove fetch and try. Your query is: @Query(value = "select  new map(c.countryId as countryId , c.countryName as countryName , c.cityList as cityList)  from Country c left join fetch c.cityList")
where you use join fetch for c.cityList but you are not fetching it in select.
Use @Query(value = "select  new map(c.countryId as countryId , c.countryName as countryName , cityList as cityList)  from Country c left join fetch c.cityList cityList")

Comment: `Dto` projection can be used instead of map. I have answered question how to use `dto` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948133/unable-to-locate-appropriate-constructor-error-for-nested-list-object-in-kotlin/60951135#60951135

Comment: this has nothing to do with the problem, the issue will remain

Comment: what is the definition of map ?

Comment: I guess @alex valuiskyi's answer in another post will cause N+1 query, I don't see dto projection was used, but lazy query. I did find defining an projection interface can solve the issue, but it just looks like that graceful to me than using a map.

Comment: To Abinash Ghosh , the map definition can be found at Expected result seciton.

Comment: My answer code does not cause `N+1 problem`. It generates one query and returns list of `dto`s (`List<com.example.dto.User>`)