# Hibernate : Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i want to retrieve data with DTO Projection using sprind data jpa, but unfortunately  when i call the method an error has occurred :

```
    [2020-05-28 21:02:03] Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.burgerbuilder.backend.DTO.Response.UserResponse]. Expected arguments are: java.util.UUID, java.lang.String , java.lang.String , java.lang.String , java.util.Collection
[select new com.burgerbuilder.backend.DTO.Response.UserResponse(u.id,u.email,u.name,u.lastName,u.authorities) from com.burgerbuilder.backend.Model.User u where u.id=:id]
```

my repository :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
@Query("select new com.burgerbuilder.backend.DTO.Response.UserResponse(u.id,u.email,u.name,u.lastName,u.authorities) from User u where u.id=:id")
Optional<UserResponse> findUserById(@Param("id") String id);}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Type(type=”uuid-char”)
private UUID id;
@NotNull
private String email;
@NotNull
private String password;
private String name;
private String lastName;
private String phoneNumber;
private String emailVerificationToken;
private boolean isEmailVerified=false;
private boolean isPhoneNumberVerified=false;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = “user”,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Authority> authorities=new ArrayList();
```

DTO Class :

```
 public class UserResponse {
    private String userId;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Authority> authorities=new ArrayList<>();

    public UserResponse(UUID userId, String email, String name, String lastName, List<Authority> authorities) {
        this.userId = userId.toString();
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.authorities=authorities;
    }
}
```

can someone help me please ?

Comment: This line seems suspect `@Type(type=”uuid-char”)` are you sure that's the type you want? - seems it should not have the annotation but I have not time to check it right now

Comment: Well, the error is pretty self-explanatory. `u.authorities` is a `Collection` (and **not** specifically a `List`).

Comment: @crizzis List is a subinterface of Collection , also i test it with Collection but nothing happened

Comment: @ZahreddineAtoui Since when can you assign a `Collection` to a param of type `List`?

Comment: @blurfus i used [@Type] to change the type of that column in the database because there is a problem with uuid in mysql database

Comment: @crizzis what should i do then  because i didn't understand you ?

Comment: The fastest would be to actually debug Hibernate's `ReflectHelper.getConstructor()` method, which is where the error is coming from. You'll see exactly why your constructor is not what Hibernate's expecting to find

Comment: @crizzis ok i will try to  debug it , thank you

Comment: The problem is that database query is able to return plain result only. Persistence provider can convert it to entities with nested entities lists. As for `dto` you have to solve the problem yourself. I have answered similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948133/unable-to-locate-appropriate-constructor-error-for-nested-list-object-in-kotlin/60951135#60951135